# How to configure bundling and minification in one solution two projects like admin and user?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

**How to configure it with bundling and min files?**

1. I have two projects in one solution, how to configure it with bundling and min files?
2. What are the changes to be done in index.html?
3. I tried by solving making changes in index.html

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you show code to  us what you have tried till now?